# Parallax effect on specified view inside nested layout

Tags: java, android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-nestedscrollview

I would like to make parallax effect on certain view inside nested scroll view.
On the top on my layout I have coordinator_layout, first child is a collapsing toolbar layout with parallax effect. Below toolbar as second child of coordinator_layout is a nested scroll view with views for 'some other content...' and between other content I have frame layout in which I would like to implement parallax on image_view, text_view1, text_view2 on scroll[image: my layout]

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should use a Parallax library to obtain this effect.
There is a bunch of them, especially [this](https://github.com/Narfss/ParallaxEverywhere) one applies parallax on TextViews and ImageViews.

Comment: Hmm most of them are quite old, I tried ParallaxEverywhere but paralax effect is not working smooth

Comment: Try using [this](https://github.com/gjiazhe/ScrollParallaxImageView?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=4759) library, is 1 year old but looks good.
On Android Arsenal you can find a lot of them.